# How can the Feeds module fetch a file from a dynamic URL?

Tags: uri, feeds

The [feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) does fine importing a source file (CSV, in my case) from an external URL. However, I'm trying to schedule Feeds to pull in a report every X days. I need Feeds to fetch at a dynamic URL,
say:
`www.example.com/report/%start-date%/%end-date%`

I'm guessing this would use the Token module, but aside from that I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

As I know Feeds doesn't have something like that, its maybe a feature that you can propose on they issue list.

A workaround its to create a small module that will work as a proxy for your dynamic address.

You will have something like that :

```
<?php

function proxy_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['proxy-url'] = array(
    'title' => 'Proxy for danymic url',
    'page callback' => 'proxy_get_contents',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
  return  $items;
}

function proxy_get_contents() {
  $url = 'http://www.example.com/report/%start-date%/%end-date%';
  $request = drupal_http_request($url);
  if ($request->code == 301 || $request->code == 304) {
    return $request->data;
  }
}
```

Comment: What a nice thinking @yvan. The only downside I can think about is the load. feeds requires its own site's page and that page has to be booted separately to fetch the actual URL. 
May be a custom fetching mechanism can do the trick anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the FeedsHTTPFetcher class and register your plugin with hook_feeds_plugins(). Then override the fetch method to handle your dynamic URL that's stored in $source_config['source'].